# How can I retrieve the features of the last step in backward regression in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am using backward regression to do the feature selection in R. After the backward feature selection is run I get a series of outputs starting from the initial set of features.

```
    Start AIC 6811.87
    Step  AIC 6809.88
    Step  AIC 6807.99
    Step  AIC 6807.63
```

I would like take the features of the last step with the minimum AIC and pass it into another model.

```
model.aic.backward <- step(fullModel, direction = "backward", trace = 1)
```

When I try to print the terms by using the below command

```
print(attr(model.aic.backward$terms,"term.labels"))
```

I still get the initial set of features which was fed into the model. Please suggest how can I achieve this.

Thank you

Comment: Can't reproduce. Works fine with `mod = step(lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars), direction = "backward"); coef(mod); attr(mod$terms, "term.labels")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model given by `step` is the "optimal" model, not the initial model.
Here is an illustrative example:

```
# Linear data generating process
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
X <- matrix(rnorm(n*5),nrow=n)
betas <- c(-1.5,2,0,-2,0,0)
y <- cbind(rep(1,n), X) %*% betas + 0.5*rnorm(n)
dtset <- data.frame(y, X)

# Initial full model
lmfit <- lm(y~., data=dtset)

# Backward selection
model.aic.backward <- step(lmfit, direction = "backward", trace = 1)
```

Here is the output of `step`

```
Start:  AIC=-137.45
y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5

       Df Sum of Sq    RSS     AIC
- X2    1      0.01  22.44 -139.41
- X5    1      0.11  22.54 -138.97
- X4    1      0.22  22.66 -138.47
<none>               22.44 -137.44
- X1    1    294.14 316.57  125.24
- X3    1    422.44 444.87  159.26

Step:  AIC=-139.41
y ~ X1 + X3 + X4 + X5

       Df Sum of Sq    RSS     AIC
- X5    1      0.12  22.56 -140.89
- X4    1      0.22  22.66 -140.45
<none>               22.44 -139.41
- X1    1    294.37 316.82  123.32
- X3    1    423.21 445.65  157.44

Step:  AIC=-140.89
y ~ X1 + X3 + X4

       Df Sum of Sq    RSS     AIC
- X4    1      0.23  22.79 -141.89
<none>               22.56 -140.89
- X1    1    299.18 321.74  122.86
- X3    1    423.79 446.35  155.59

Step:  AIC=-141.89
y ~ X1 + X3

       Df Sum of Sq    RSS     AIC
<none>               22.79 -141.89
- X1    1    300.89 323.67  121.46
- X3    1    431.38 454.17  155.33
```

and here the model inside the `model.aic.backward` object:

```
summary(model.aic.backward)


############
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ X1 + X3, data = dtset)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.2168 -0.3057 -0.0047  0.3693  1.0416 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -1.51531    0.04885  -31.02   <2e-16 ***
X1           1.94126    0.05424   35.79   <2e-16 ***
X3          -2.01862    0.04711  -42.85   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4847 on 97 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9693,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9687 
F-statistic:  1531 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

This is the model after backward selection, not the initial model.

Hope this can help you.